# Validate engine always return false

Tags: jquery

i am trying to apply jquery validations form my page contents and i followed this website http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-form-plugin/ and addded all js and css files with all reference in my page also, but when i click to submit form and validate my page using

```
if (!$("#frmUsercreation").validationEngine('validate')) {
    return false;
}
else {
   //my code
}
```

its return always false. even all fields are filled its not hitting else part

Comment: checkout `console` there might be something `undefined`?

Comment: when i leave some mandatory fields empty validation error is coming(pop msg) and page is not submitting but when i fill all data and submit(from submit button i am calling onclick method and in that method i written above validation if condition.) then also page not submitting and data not storing in database.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may also benefit from reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other [Stack Overflow help articles on "Asking"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).